# jquery User Agent error in ie

Tags: jquery, asp.net, html, internet-explorer

```
User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0; InfoPath.2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.04506.648; .NET CLR 3.5.21022; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E)
Timestamp: Fri, 22 Jun 2012 05:20:36 UTC
Message: Expected identifier, string or number
Line: 39
Char: 1
Code: 0
URI: [http://app.eschooltrack.com/scripts/functions.js][1]
```

With this error complete **jQuery** file is not working in `IE` after converting to asp.net version, its working fine in other browsers and **HTML** version,

please help me.

Comment: try removing the comma after height:20, and height:160,

Comment: Thank you its cleared some problem, still have another like that in same page any way you r given a way +1 for you

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the comma after height:20, and height:160, in your functions.js

```
$(function(){
$('#alerts').vTicker({ 
speed: 500,
pause: 4000,
animation: 'fade',
mousePause: true,
showItems: 2,
direction: 'up',
height:20
});
});



$(function(){
$('#news').vTicker({ 
speed: 500,
pause: 4000,
animation: 'fade',
mousePause: true,
showItems: 2,
direction: 'up',
height:160
});
});
```

Comment: I was done this, only working this functions but not working other functions

Comment: sorry i dint get you. Can you see what firebug(ig you have it installed) console shwing? or atleast error console in Firefox showing?

Comment: Don't have problem with Firefox/Chrome, problem with IE. Other functions are not working like starting you can find add class function

Comment: Ya all scripts placed in those same path, and all functions called in functions.js